# Wicket Internationalization : Multiple Properties file for Multiple Pages?

Tags: internationalization, wicket

the wicket internationalization example available has the following file structure

```
HomePage.java
HomePage.html
HomePage.properties
WicketApplication.java
HomePage_nl.properties
```

Now when creating a project with multiple HTML pages, for example i have
HomePage.html and Login.html, is there a way that i can save all key-value pair in single property for a particular language
or 
i will have to have to create all these files

```
HomePage.properties
HomePage_nl.properties
Login.properties
Login_nl.properties
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wicket will try to find message resources using the following rules:

1. Wicket will try to find the message starting from the `Page` and drilling down to the specific `Component` through the *component hierarchy* of the `Page`. Notice this is a **top-down** search.
2. When a message is not found in the component hierarchy, it will be looked for in the `Application` class.

The lookup for a resource in every class works in the following way :

1. Localised searches appending the locale to the file name (`Login_nl.properties`, then `Login.properties`), just like Java's [`ResourceBundle`s do](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)).
2. **Down-top** through the *class hierarchy*. That means that if a resource is not found in a class, it will be searched in its superclasses all the way until it hits `java.lang.Object`.

So, in your specific case, if `Login` is a `Panel` inside `HomePage`, you can just define the resources in `HomePage(_nl).properties`. Also, if there are specific application-wide messages, remember that you can define them in `WicketApplication(_nl).properties`.

You might find the following Wicket wiki page : [Everything about Wicket internationalization](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Everything+about+Wicket+internationalization) useful, it elaborates on this matter.

> *(...)*. This is facilitated by first looking up the message
>   (following the algorithm above) for every parent in the component
>   hierarchy (aka page hierarchy). Every component can override the
>   messages of its child components, so the search starts at the page's
>   properties and then trickles down to the component that uses it (yes,
>   its top-down). In order to make overrides specific to a certain child
>   component, you can prefix the message key with the component id of the
>   child. See ComponentStringResourceLoader for more details.
>
> If no message was found in the page hierarchy, another search starts
>   which will look at your application class and its super classes. So
>   Wicket first looks at MyApplication.properties (provided MyApplication
>   is the name of your application) and then up the class hierarchy,
>   passing org.apache.wicket.Application, up to java.lang.Object. This is
>   how Wicket provides its many default i18n texts.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i just have another query. is it prefered to write different properties file for different panel or should i include all key-value in WicketApplication(_nl).properties. which is more appropriate?

Comment: It depends on how you plan to (re)use components. I'd generally advise against defining all resources in the application.properties, it will make overriding of the messages in reused components throughout the application more difficult.

Comment: Glad that helped :) Actually, ignore my last comment. It will not make it more difficult. You could always define the resource override in the component hierarchy.